# How to use 4 arguments to make a function?

Tags: r, statistics

I have to make a function ans(a, b, x, y), which returns the value x, if a=1 
and b=1, the value y, if a=1 and b=0, and the value 0 otherwise.

I am using this command:

```
ans<-function(a, b, x, y){ 
ifelse(a= 1 & b= 1, x, a= 1 & b= 0, y, 0)}
```

can someone guide about this please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you type `?ifelse()`, the options are test,yes,no.
In your case, You have multiple conditions. So maybe what you want is something similar to:

```
ans<-function(a, b, x, y)
{ 
if(a==1 && b==1)
{
print(x)
}
else if (a==1 && b==0)
{
print(y)
}
else {
print(0)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use:

```
  ans<-function(a,b,x,y){
  target<-c(a,b)
  ifelse(target<=0|target>1,0,ifelse(all(target==1),x,y))[1]
 }
 ans(1,0,4,5)
[1] 5
```

Test:

```
     ans(9,0,4,5)
    #[1] 0
```